# i need a custom query for some product attributes in magento

Tags: php, magento

i need a custom `magento` `query` that gets the following values from database:

```
    product name,
    product link,
    product description,
    product image,
    product price,
    product SKU.
```

Comment: Please share what you have tried.

Comment: i did not try any query because i have not any knowledge about magento

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This SQL will give you the product name. You can modify this query to add `attribute_id` and `entity_type_id` for SKU etc.

```
SELECT `value` AS product_name
FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar
WHERE entity_type_id = (SELECT entity_type_id FROM eav_entity_type WHERE entity_type_code = 'catalog_product')
AND attribute_id = (SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code = 'name' AND entity_type_id = (SELECT entity_type_id FROM eav_entity_type WHERE entity_type_code = 'catalog_product'))
```

once you have multiple `attribute_id` and `entity_type_id` then use `IN` keyword with `SQL`

Answer (score 2):

Try these,

```
$sku = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getName();
$sku = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getDescription();
$sku = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getPrice();
$sku = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())->getSku();
echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(50,50);
```